# how can i create subdomains on azure dynamically from my c# asp.net mvc application.?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, azure, azure-web-app-service, subdomain

I am developing on c# asp.net mvc and hosting is on azure portal. I am creating a website where I am giving my site as rent to many of users. As user is subscribed to my site he can get a subdomain of my website. Like my website URL is **site.com** and the user subscribed can get **user1.site.com**. I want this to happen dynamically as a user is subscribed to my site. As i am developing on azure portal so i need to create subdomains on azure from my web app dynamically!

Comment: Based on information in the question it does not look you are should be fine serving all domains from the same app - so coding part is duplicate, configuring DNS is not on-topic for SO (but presumably you already sorted out how you going to do that anyway)

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  I just want to create new subdomains from my c# application on azure using power shell scripting!

Comment: You are welcome to [edit] the question to clarify what you want to create (note that "create subdomain with powershell" is very unclear so don't just edit you comment into the question) - list exact things you want to create like DNS records (including what DNS provider you use), whether you need to provision new Azure instances/sites/whatever, whether you need to purchase SSL certificates,...

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov i will surely edit the question! actually i have very little knowledge about domains! Do you understand what my target is to achieve?? what scenario i want to meet? 
i just want to make subdomains on azure from my c# application! I am using azure hosting and domain from namecheap. forget the power shell thing for a while!